# How do you create a sub-directory for a website?

Tags: html, subdirectory

I am likely just not searching this the right way, but I have no idea how to add a sub directory to a website, you know www.websitename/HOWDOIADDTHISPART

I have my index.html set up but now I want to add pages and have made some with html but not sure how to link to them, my index.html works with  www.websitename/index.html so i figured i could link the html name but it doesn't do anything. (i get 404 not found of course)

as I said i have been looking, for over an hour, it seems like an easy enough thing, it is pretty essential to any website, but I just can't find an answer. I would really appreciate anything, a link, correction of wording, whatever.

Comment: Make a subdirectory in your WWW root dir that can be accessed by the user that your webserver runs under with the name that you want to put after your domain (ex: `www.mysite.com/thisisthedirnameyouuse/afile.html`), and put the files in there.

Comment: Ryan J means 'make a new folder' when he says 'subdirectory'. It works exactly the same way as your files and folders on an OS (look at your local file paths and work it out), except the slashes go the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you upload the other HTML pages in the same folder you can reach them with www.your site.com/page name.HTML

If in the index.HTML folder you create a subfolder and a file in that subfolder you can reach the page with www.yoursite.com/subfoldername/pagename.HTML